# onAfterRender plugin issue

Tags: plugin, system-plugin

Both the PHP and the JS is tested and works in a module.  But there's really no need for a module this is a plugin.  I'm quite new to this so I thought onAfterRender would work, but nothing seems to happen.

What is the problem and in the future, what is the best way to troubleshoot this?

Also, as this will load on every page, should I be using a .js file and then using defer to improve performance?

**koy_alias_as_body_class.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2017 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * Plugin class for adding the alias to the body
 *
 * @since  1.6
 */
class plgSystemKoy_alias_as_body_class extends JPlugin
{

    public function onBeforeCompileHead()
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        // only insert the script in the frontend
        if ($app->isClient('site'))
        {
            var_dump(1); exit;
            $prefix = "";
            if ($params->get('prefix'))
            {
                $prefix = $params->get('prefix');
            }

            $menu      = $app->getMenu();
            $active    = $menu->getActive();
            $alias     = $active->alias;

            JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() 
                {
                    document.body.classList.add("' . $prefix . $alias  . '");
                });
            ');
        }
    }
}
```

**koy_alias_as_body_class.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <extension version="3.8" type="plugin" group="system" method="upgrade">
        <name>PLG_SYSTEM_KOY_ALIAS_AS_BODY_CLASS</name>
        <author>Moi</author>
        <creationDate>January 2019</creationDate>
        <copyright>Copyright (C) 2005 - 2019 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright>
        <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
        <authorEmail>info@site.com</authorEmail>
        <authorUrl>https://www.site.com</authorUrl>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>KOY_ALIAS_AS_BODY_CLASS_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="koy_alias_as_body_class">koy_alias_as_body_class.php</filename>
        <folder>language</folder>
    </files>
    <!-- Update servers -->
    <updateservers>
        <server type="extension" priority="1" name="koy_alias_as_body_class">https://www.kindofuseful.com/downloads/joomla/modules/koy_alias_as_body_class/updates.xml</server>
    </updateservers>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="prefix" type="text" default="m" label="KOY_ALIAS_AS_BODY_CLASS_PREFIX_LABEL" description="KOY_ALIAS_AS_BODY_CLASS_PREFIX_DESCRIPTION" size="10" />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

Comment: Can you try adding a simple `var_dump(1); exit;` inside `if ($app->isClient('site')) { }`, just to see if the plugin is actually being executed.

Comment: Done, what should happen?  The site appears to load normally.

Comment: The site should go blank and display a single `1` in the top left. Are you sure the plugin is enabled and the class name is correct?

Comment: I copied and pasted the XML to show.  I copied and pasted the file names too so they should be correct.  It all looks ok to me but perhaps my eyes are tired.  Is the class name done correctly?

Comment: Also are the languages done correctly?  For some reason they show the literal string and not the langauge.  I've done it this way in modules before and it has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've debugged this now. I'll write this down in simple steps:

1. Change the PHP file name to `koy_alias_as_body_class.php`
2. Change the XML file name to `koy_alias_as_body_class.xml`
3. Change the `class` name to `class plgSystemKoy_alias_as_body_class`
4. Replace the event `onAfterRender` with `onBeforeCompileHead`
5. In the XML file, replace this:

---

```
 <filename plugin="plg_system_koy_alias_as_body_class">plg_system_koy_alias_as_body_class.php</filename>
```

with this:

```
<filename plugin="koy_alias_as_body_class">koy_alias_as_body_class.php</filename>
```

Hope this helps

---

Also you cannot call params by using `$params->get('prefix')`.  To see the params you need first to use `$this->params`.  Unlike in a module you cannot use get.  As the params are in an array inside `$this` you can use this syntax

`$this->params['prefix']`

Comment: Ah, I see.  Ok, so from my reading I should never use plg_system in the file names.  I was wondering why none of the others were in folders called that.  But I should still call my zip file `plg_system_xxx_xxx` as reasonably good practice right?  Thanks a million, when will we see you at Joomla! London?  We're on meetup now https://www.meetup.com/Joomla-User-Group-London/

Comment: Hmm, still no joy.  That's odd.  Should I update my code?

Comment: Yeah please do and I'll take another look tomorrow

Comment: Crap.  Got the var_dump working but still no class on the body.  And still no language strings.

Comment: Fixed and updated your answer.

Comment: @Eoin - Ah yes. I did fix the params when installing on my site but forgot to mention it in the steps.